# Android - Language resources on cloud

Tags: android, android-resources

Is it possible to save the language xml resources on the cloud (i.e. Firebase)?
I am building dynamic application that has changing UI and I want the resources for language values to be constantly updated per the changes in UI but still keep android built-in support for multiple language resources

Comment: **YES YOU CAN**

Comment: it is possible, but you have to implement it yourself. There is no built-in support.